# Find the probability of picking red colored ball out of an urn?

Tags: probability

There are $R=1500$ red colored balls, $B=1200$ blue colored balls and $G=900$ golden balls in the urn. What is the probability that the $100$th ball picked from the urn is a red one, given that every time a ball is picked, it is not put back in the urn?

Answer (score 1):

Without any information on the colors of the 99 balls already eliminated, the probability for the 100th ball to be red is the same as the probability for the first ball to be red: 5/12.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the 100th ball picked from the urn is a red one is the same as the probability that the first ball picked from the urn is a red one.

This is discussed for the case of cards [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262238/card-probabilities/262251). The idea is the same.